# Spring Injection between two projects

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-rest

I am new to Spring and I have below query.

I have a Spring Project which just perform the Database Operations. It has Entity Class and Repository say Employee and EmployeeRepository.

I have another project which act as RestWebService (in Spring). I want to inject EmployeeRepository in the controller. Both the project are Web project and deployed on same application server.

Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by separated projects? Can you access Repository class in your Controller?

Comment: @sovas separate project means two different project, developed by different developers but deployed on same application server. I want to Achieve some thing like EJB where EJB is deployed sepratly and using Initial Context or Remote Interface that can be injected in any project.

Answer (score 3):

If the projects are deployed as separate applications on an application server, they cannot access each other's beans. Each application is maintaining its own Application Context.

The better way would be having just one application deployed, which has the other project as dependency (using maven for example).

Of course easier would be having just one project.

Comment: No he cant cause @Autowired annotation (package scanner)is not going to work.Right??

Comment: I want to do injection like EJB. In EJB injection can be done using Remote interface. Is there anything like that in Spring ?